# Multiple Comparison operators?

Tags: c, comparison, operators

im having trouble using multiple operators while programing a simple FizzBuz in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (0 < n < 10000){
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i ++) {
            if (i % 15 == 0) {
                puts("TikTak");
            }
            else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                puts("Tik");
            }
            else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                puts("Tak");
            }
            else {
                printf("%d\n", i);
            }
        }
    }else{
        printf("-1");
    }
}
```

Now the "if (0 < n < 10000)" comparison operators is ignored for some reason, but if I rewrite it as:

```
if (n < 10000 && n > 0){
```

it will work as intended.

Am I missing something? Ill be honest Im newbie in C programing. haha

**EDIT:** Thanks everybody, haha that was quite simple. I thought that might be the issue I just waned to make surebecause "0 < n < 10000" is litteraly how the assigment says it should look like.

Again, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps reading a text book on C would help

Comment: It is quite simple - C does not use the mathematical comparison symbology.`if (0 < n < 10000)` ==> `if (0 < n && n < 10000)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite this condition

```
if (0 < n < 10000){
```

like

```
if (0 < n && n < 10000){
```

Otherwise the original condition looks like

```
if (( 0 < n ) < 10000){
```

and the result of the expression `0 < n` is either `1` or `0`. So in fact you are comparing `0` or `1` with `10000`.

From the C Standard (6.5.8 Relational operators)

> 6 Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than
>   or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the
>   specified relation is true and 0 if it is false.107) The result has
>   type int.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `0 < n < 10000` is equivalent to `(0 < n) < 10000` which means you check if `0 < n` is less than `10000`, which it will always be (the result of a comparison like `0 < n` will be zero or one).